# PHP double arrow notation for instances of an class(es)

Tags: php, oop

I would be grateful if someone explained to me the use of double arrow notation in PHP. I suggest is a double classes and instantiation of that classes, but I am not sure. Some examples will be good. Thanks.

Something like this:

```
$obj->prop->methd();
```

Comment: this is not php related, even c with struct you can have something like that :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This just indicates that `$obj` has a property that is a class of some kind rather than an atomic variable.  The inner class has a method `method()` which is called from the second arrow operator.  You could also access properties of the inner class via the second arrow.

```
// Access the inner property
echo $obj->prop->inner_property
// 1234

// Call the inner method
$obj->prop->method();
// I'm the method!
```

The class definitions might be something like:

```
class obj
{
   // Will hold an instance of class Something
   public $prop;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->prop = new Something();
   }
}

class Something 
{
   public $inner_property = 1234;

   public function method() {
     echo "I'm the method!";
   }
}
```

Comment: Does it have to have a constructor in order to my example to work?

Comment: No, the `prop` object could have been set like `$obj->prop = new Something()` at any point in the code.  It doesn't have to be assigned in the constructor

Comment: Is this way of code equal as extending a class and inheriting inherited class methods and props?

Comment: @Dejan No it's not the same. Consider a class `Garage` which holds an array of `Cars`  The `Cars` don't inherit from the `Garage`, but are contained within:  `$garage->cars[0]->get_max_speed()` gets the max speed of the first car in the garage, but the `max_speed` is strictly a property of the `Cars`. You could not do `$garage->cars[0]->get_num_parking_spaces()` because the cars don't inherit the garage's `get_num_parking_spaces()` method

Comment: Does `protected` and `private` attributes apply to double arrow notation chain, like in extending a class?

Answer (score 5):

As an example, take for instance two classes:

```
<?php

class a {
    function test() {
        echo "test";
    }
}

class b {
    var $prop = null;
    function __construct() {
        $this->prop = new a();
    }
}

$obj = new b();
var_dump($obj);
$obj->prop->test();

?>
```

http://codepad.org/aEeRs45A

Class `a` gives `$prop` a method when `b` is instantiated and the constructor is called. `$prop` in `b` is an object of class `b`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your method returns an object you can call the methods of that object too, and so on.

So here's an example of how you can chain methods of a class.

```
<?php
class MyTest {
    public function Hello() {
        echo "Hello ";
        return $this;
    }

    public function World() {
        echo "World!";
    }
}

$h = new MyTest();
$h->Hello()->World();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`prop` is a property of `$obj` which is also an object. Therefore, to access `prop`'s method, you must use the arrow operator again.

Answer (score 1):

$obj->prop is variable defined like

```
class class1{
    public $prop = new class2;
}

class2{
    function methd(){
        echo "methd function called";
    }
}


$obj->prop->methd();
```